# Log1p and other numpy functions on a DataFrame doesn't yield the same result when using iloc() before or after operation

Tags: pandas, numpy, precision

I have a data frame with data in multiple columns. When I apply log1p and slice with iloc, the rounding change whether I first apply log1p and slice or slice and apply log1p. The same behavior happens with other numpy functions.

```
data = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(.001,.001,10000),np.random.normal(.001,.001,10000)]).T
x = np.log1p(data).iloc[:,0]
y = np.log1p(data.iloc[:,0])
diff = x.subtract(y,axis = 0)
diff.mean() 

Out: 4.153955452453495e-21
```

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem. What version of pandas, numpy and python are you using?

Comment: Pandas 0.25.1, Numpy 1.16.5 and Python 3.7.4

Comment: You may want to consider upgrading pandas and numpy. I am running pandas version 1.1.0, numpy version 1.18.1 and python 3.7.6.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, cannot upgrade to test.